# No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql, on server with Maven (Java)

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, maven, jdbc

My Exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://SOME_ID_HERE.SOME_NUMBERS_HERE.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/DB_NAME?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true
```

My project is using Maven, so I have previously had success by just adding libraries to my POM.xml file, and it would work both in eclipse as well as on the server that runs my web app/site.

My POM.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.39</version>
</dependency>
```

This is where get the connection:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://SOME_ID_HERE.SOME_NUMBERS_HERE.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/DB_NAME_TWO?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true", userName, password);
```

On my own PC running eclipse, everything works fine, just adding the library in the POM makes it work. What do I need to do to make it work on the server?

I tried adding `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` before getting the connection, but this caused it to basically just crash without giving me any errors.

I've also tried downloading `mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar`, but I am unsure where to put it. The server was custom built by someone else before I was hired, and doesn't necessarily have a lib folder, or I don't know where/what it is.

I've also tried adding `-cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar:.` or `-cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar` to the execution of my `java -jar /program.jar`. Which did not seem to make any difference.

I may be using some kind of pooling, if that is relevant (heard some mentions in comments, while searching for a solution, that it may be).

```
java.util.concurrent.Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
```

**How do I get jdbc:mysql driver to work on my server?** 
Please be very specific when coming with suggestions, thank you very much for your time.

Comment: What sort of Java code are you deploying? Servlet?  To what sort of server infrastructure? tomcat? jetty? These questions are relevant because each setup has its own way of handling jar files bundled with a deployed code base.

Comment: It's running on Debian/Linux, but I am not sure if my application is using any of those standard infrastructures. Is there a way to find out? From the code itself it does not seem to expose anything like tomcat/jetty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the things I mentioned in the bottom of the post apparently did work.
Downloading the jar file for mysql-connector-java did work (possibly also requires to add it to classport with the export command). **When I changed the version in Maven to match the one I had downloaded**, I can now connect.
The difference between the two was obviously a mistake.